# Concatenate two arrays by their lowest and highest values

Tags: arrays, swift

I need to concatenate two arrays

```
let array1 = [2,10,3,11]
let array2 = [10,1,5,8]
```

result array should be a sum of the highest value in first array and lowest in the second one like so
First largest value from array1: 11 and lowest from second: 1. Then we remove both numbers from first and second and so on. In this order:

1. 11 + 1
2. 10 + 5
3. 3 + 8
4. 2 + 10

Result - [12, 15, 11, 12]

I know how to do it by creating temp arrays, but would like to know if there is any way to do it by using functions like `map, enumerate` and so on. Thank you.

Comment: You mean the sum of *highest* value in first array and *lowest* in the second one, right? Also step 1 should be 11 + 1, not 1 + 1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sort the arrays (in decreasing resp. increasing order), zip them, and add:

```
let array1 = [2,10,3,11]
let array2 = [10,1,5,8]

let result = zip(array1.sorted(by: >), array2.sorted()).map(+)
print(result) // [12, 15, 11, 12]
```

`zip()` returns a sequence of pairs from the two (sorted) arrays.
Then `map()` is applied to this sequence to get an array of the
sums.

Sorting the arrays once is faster than repeatedly locating
and removing the largest (resp. smallest) element.

Comment: An analogous but semantically slightly different approach would be to use the default `<` operator as the predicate for sorting both arrays, but apply `reversed()` to the former, i.e., `let result = zip(array1.sorted().reversed(), array2.sorted()).map(+)`. I believe there should be no additional overhead using the reverse order view.